# MultipartFormData(Map(filename -> List(abcd)),List(),List(),List()) scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am writing code in play framework for some function and My request contains following in body:

`MultipartFormData(Map(filename -> List(abcd)),List(),List(),List())`.

How do I extract "abcd" from this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using an Action with a parser:

```
def ... = Action (parse.urlFormEncoded) {r =>
  // "abcd"
  val filename = r.body("filename").head

  ...
}
```

Otherwise:

```
def ... = Action {r =>
  // "abcd"
  r.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("filename").head
  ...
}
```

But you might consider using Play's form support:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaForms